# How can i find the distance between the yellow line and the green line?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The yellow line present the bottom border of menuStrip1 control.

And the green color present the top of the pictureBox1 control.

I want to calculate the space between the two controls( same as the space between the two lines yellow and green ).

This is what i did in pictureBox1 paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int distance;
            float penWidth = 15F;
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, (int)penWidth);
            Pen myPen1 = new Pen(Brushes.Red, (int)penWidth);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width - 1, pictureBox1.Height - 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen1, 0, pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen1, 0,0,0,pictureBox1.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen1, pictureBox1.Width, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            distance = menuStrip1.Height - pictureBox1.Height;
        }
```

And this is the menuStrip1 paint event:

```
private void menuStrip1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            float penWidth = 15F;
            Pen myPen1 = new Pen(Brushes.Yellow, (int)penWidth);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen1, 0, menuStrip1.Height, menuStrip1.Width, menuStrip1.Height);
        }
```

The result is:

[image: Yellow-Green]

And in the pictureBox1 paint event and in the menuStrip1 paint event the lines i drawed in red green and yellow what they are present by: Width or Height or Left or Right or Top or Bottom ? I drawed the red lines manual also the green and yellow but how do i know if the bottom line is bottom and what right or left ?

Comment: The distance between the two controls is: `PictureBox1.Top - MenuStrip1.Bottom`. Are you looking for something different than that?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to calculate space between two object the logic is simple you have to access it's y location both of object and then do division between two location picturebox.y - menustrip.y

i have just wrote simple code just for you

```
        int x = menuStrip1.Location.Y;
        int p = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
        int result = p - x;
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

i just tested these code and just works fine good luck buddy